# Ruby/Rails - Double Pipe with blank dataset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an object that is coming back blank and here is what I would like to do

```
@photo = [] # this is coming back blank, but it won't do the correct comparison in the ||
@sanitized_photos = PhotoPresenter.new(@photo).to_json || PhotoPresenter.default_layout.to_json
```

Any thoughts on how to make it work without a beefy if statement

UPDATED ::: Here is a copy of my presenter that works pretty well.  I know i have put collection logic inside here but it works the most clean way

```
class PhotoPresenter < Presenter

  def initialize(photo)
    @photo = photo
  end

  def to_gallery
    {
      "thumb" => @photo.image.url(:thumb),
      "image" => @photo.image.url(:large),
      "big" => @photo.image.url,
      "title" => @photo.attachable.name
    }
  end

  def self.blank_gallery
    {
        "thumb" => help.polymorphic_photo_url(nil, :large),
        "image" => help.polymorphic_photo_url(nil, :large),
        "big" => help.polymorphic_photo_url(nil, :large),
        "title" => "No photo provided"
      }
  end

  def self.as_gallery(photos)
    unless photos.blank?
      photos.collect{|object| self.new(object).to_gallery}.to_json
    else
      blank_gallery.to_json
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: What's wrong with adding a class method that returns `default_layout` if the photo list is empty? Then you could `PhotoPresenter.x(@photo).to_json`.

Comment: mu is too short.  I'm not sure I follow the difference as to what I did with the as_gallery.  Must be missing something.  You mean just set something in the initialize to return the blank_gallery.  Could you possibly answer the question with an example.  Then I could accept the answer if it is super awesome :)  Im doing this now. PhotoPresenter.as_gallery(@photos) and it will return the default if the set is empty. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, I think your `as_gallery` is what I was thinking of. Push the logic down into the model so that you only have to worry about it in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@sanitized_photos = @photo.any? ? PhotoPresenter.new(@photo).to_json : PhotoPresenter.default_layout.to_json
```

That being said you are much better of moving this logic into PhotoPresenter class initializer

Comment: Yuriy, I currently have it working as you have it there.  Do you have away to do this without the if condition.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this in my presenter but don't have a good way yet to get the code working.  I can refactor later...Thanks!